# How to make sure subprocess Popen is spreading the created instances across many CPU cores in an optimize way in Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, multiprocessing

I'm programming for windows, and in my python 3 app i am using subprocess Popen to run around 32 instances of an application.

now lets say i have a 32 core CPU, will the Windows operating system automatically spread the instances across the cores in an optimize way? or do i need to specify any flag in Popen or do something else for it to do so?

**Basically i want to give these 32 instances the highest possible priority and want to make sure these 32 instances of the application are using the cores the best way, and for example if i have 32 core, neither 2 instances should go in one core**, I'm just not sure how can i achieve this?

Comment: Popen creates independent programs that will run however the operating system thinks they should run. Windows will spread them out over all of the CPUs unless you are running in some sort of environment that has restricted that. Normally, that is not the case.

Comment: @tdelaney so in normal environments, how can i make sure windows is spreading them across many cores in an optimized way? how can i force windows to spread these applications across many cores the best way possible ( because it might for example put 5 of them in one core and 10 in other core instead of each of them in 1 of 32 core)

Comment: Basically i want to give these 32 instances the highest priority and want to make sure these 32 application are using the cores the best way, and for example if i have 32 core, neither 2 instances should go in one core

Comment: you should not worry about this, as OS will do a lot better job assigning processes to CPUs than you can possibly do. In fact, I'm not aware of any OS that would allow to do this from user space.

Comment: Windows doesn't let cores sit idle while there is work to do so the processes will naturally spread out over all of the cores. For most workloads, the default scheduler is the best. You can increase process priority so that your processes win over other things running on the system and you can also set processor affinity to restrict the CPU where the code is run. Sometimes this helps, sometimes its a disaster, so experimentation is good. Unfortunately I don't recall how to set this on Windows. Hopefully someone else knows.

Comment: With only 32 cores, there's probably only one processor group, so you don't have to worry about balancing the load across groups. (Processes are assigned to processor groups in round-robin order, anyway, which is generally good enough.) If you're micro-managing the processing load, you can set the group-relative scheduling [affinity](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setprocessaffinitymask) of each process. But generally it should work out okay to let the OS dispatch ready threads to any available processor in the group, without restricting affinity.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution for your thinking would be Pool() in multiprocessing in Python. Please read the docs here, https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html , for detailed information.

Basically, the Pool object offers a convenient means of parallelizing the execution of a function(in your case we shall say an application) across multiple input values, distributing the input data across processes (data parallelism).

Below is a sample snippet that can used to create N number of parallel processes, which will be evenly distributed to all the cores of the CPU.

```py
import datetime
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def init_application(x):
    time.sleep(2)
    # Initiate your application here, which will be added to the pool for processing.
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool()  # Distributes to all available CPU cores
    print(p.map(init_application, range(10)))
```

Hope this clarifies your doubt. Also, the above snippet is a sample implementation of Pool() in python. Please modify according your requirement.

Thanks,
AG